# How to create dynamic fields in openerp 7 module?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I am working on creating an openerp 7 module, I have been using eclipse IDE with Python for running the code. I want to give the feature of creating dynamic fields. I want to call a form in which the details(name,data type,size) of the field will be provided by user to create that new field. I have no such idea for dynamic field creation . plz help me.

Hopes for sugestion

Comment: copy of post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569828/how-to-create-a-dynamic-view-on-openerp/6731739#6731739

Answer (score 1):

You can use fields_view_get function in the osv for creating dynamic fields. Inherit the fields_view_get() function.

```
def fields_view_get(self, cr, uid, view_id=None, view_type='form', context={}, toolbar=False):
    result = super(<your_class_name>, self).fields_view_get(cr, uid, view_id, view_type, context=context, toolbar=toolbar)
    ###your modification in the view
    ###result['fields'] will give you the fields. modify it if needed
    ###result['arch'] will give you the xml architecture. modify it if needed
    return result
```

First check what is getting for your. Then build an idea on it and proceed. You can find an example in account module, account_invoice.py file

Comment: I am not getting you and I cant find this func in account_invoice.py file