# Extracting expression

Tags: python, regex, expression, extract, text-extraction

I have a expression and I want to extract it in python 2.6. Here is the example:

```
[a]+[c]*0.6/[b]-([a]-[f]*0.9)
```

this going to:

```
(
  '[a]',
  '+',
  '[c]',
  '*',
  '0.6',
  '/',
  '[b]',
  '-',
  '(',
  '[a]',
  '-',
  '[f]',
  '*',
  '0.9',
  ')',
)
```

I need it a list. Please give me a hand. Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to make a calculator or something?

Comment: Not calculate. I need extract it like example.

Comment: ... And what are you going to do once you extracted it?

Comment: I new to python. I have a backspace button and when it clicked I need remove last element of list /I'm going to use it via stack./. I think it's very easy way to do it.

Comment: `mylist.pop()` will remove the last element of a list.

Comment: So I need a list. How to extract an expression? Expression is a string.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582403/safe-expression-parser-in-python

Comment: I don't need a parse it. I need a extract it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> expr = '[a]+[c]*0.6/[b]-([a]-[f]*0.9)'
>>> re.findall('(?:\[.*?\])|(?:\d+\.*\d*)|.', expr)
['[a]', '+', '[c]', '*', '0.6', '/', '[b]', '-', '(', '[a]', '-', '[f]', '*', '0.9', ')']
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a list of regular expressions to match each token, something like:

```
import re
tokens = [r'\[.?\]', r'\(', r'\)', r'\+', r'\*', r'\-', r'/', r'\d+?.\d+', r'\d+']
regex = re.compile('|'.join(tokens))
```

Then you could use `findall` on your expression to return a list of matches:

```
>>> regex.findall('[a]+[c]*0.6/[b]-([a]-[f]*0.9)')
<<< 
['[a]',
 '+',
 '[c]',
 '*',
 '0.6',
 '/',
 '[b]',
 '-',
 '(',
 '[a]',
 '-',
 '[f]',
 '*',
 '0.9',
 ')']
```