# Concatenate string with if statement eg.: if 5 "> 4":

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm wondering if it is possible to do that?

```
s = "> 4"
if 5 s:
    print("Yes it is.")
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  There is probably a better way to do what you need to do.

Comment: I have string that will be changed, like set of options, and each option represents condition. - oh and "condition string" is generated by someone else - AI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `eval`.

```
s = "> 4"
if eval("5"+s):
    print("Yes it is.")
```

[Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) is the documentation on `eval`.

Note that if you don't know what, exactly, is in your input string, `eval` is extremely insecure. Use with caution.

Answer (score 3):

This can easily be done using [`eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). However, `eval()` is [pretty dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1832957/367273) and is best avoided.

For other ideas, see [Safe expression parser in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582403/safe-expression-parser-in-python)

I think the best approach depends on where `s` comes from:

1) If it's user input, you certainly don't want to use `eval()`. An expression parser is probably the way to go.

2) If `s` is set programmatically, you're probably better off turning it into a function:

```
pred = lambda x:x > 4
if pred(5):
    print("Yes it is.")
```

Comment: Hm, I'm always concern about security issue i think i will `"> 5".split(' ')` and match (>, <, >=, <=) and int([1])

Comment: But if you use split, you're assuming that there will be a space in the input. `">5"` is a perfectly valid comparison, but `split` won't help you extract the operator.

Comment: I do, good point to remember. I know, i will have to `if` all cases.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that what you really want to do is store the comparison "> 4" and use it somewhere, I would suggest something like the following:

```
import operator

class Comparison(object):
    def __init__(self, operator, value):
        self.operator = operator
        self.value = value

    def apply(self, value):
        return self.operator(value, self.value)

s = Comparison(operator.gt, 4)

if s.apply(5):
    print("Yes it is.")
```