# Verify string as valid C code

Tags: python, c, verification

I would like to verify that a given string is valid C code in the context of

```c
int main() {
    double x[3];
    <insert code here>;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Effectively, I would like the verification to

```py
verifyC('x[0]*x[0] + x[1] + 1') // pass
verifyC('x[0]*x[0] + x[1] +') // fail, syntax error
verifyC('x[0]*x[0] + a') // fail, `a` undefined
```

What would be a good way of verification?

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me. Should function check given string semantically, or only syntactically? According to your code, the given string will be "pasted" into C code. However, in that case both of them are not correct, because there is no semicolon at the end of each line. So, please, be more specific: try to explain the goal, not the way of achieving.

Comment: write a parser. period. if you face issues in that, we can help. currently, as it is written, it's too broad to answer.

Comment: Use a parser like [pycparser](https://github.com/eliben/pycparser)

Comment: do you know what `^` means in C? :)

Comment: do you expect a statement or a block of code? what is considered "valid"?

Comment: You will have to write a C language parser. Or a C language expression parser, at least...

But why do you declare a `double x[3]` array? Do you really want just to *verify* a string is a valid expression, or also to *execute* the calculations defined by the expression...?

Comment: Should `x[3] + 5` be reported valid? Should `double a=1; x[0] += a` be? Should `x[0] = system("rm *")` be? They are all "valid", compilable C! If only simple expressions ought to be checked, look in to an expression parser instead of handing the problem to a full language parser.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way would be to just try to compile a small sample program containing the string you want to check.

This way you get your snippet checked by the real C compiler. This will be far easier and much more reliable than trying to implement all the C parsing and checking in the Python program.

Comment: Is there a way to get this done programmatically from the python script?

Comment: @NicoSchlömer: Sure, use `import subprocess` and call `gcc`.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer: The [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module lets you start external programs like the C compiler, and check their exit status.

Answer (score 1):

Replace all occurrences of your known variables with a numeric constant.  In your code, that would be `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]`. Note that in C lots of intermediate whitespace is allowed, even inside variables: `x [ 1 ]` is valid. (Also: `x[01]` is valid. `x[0x01]` is valid. If the array is larger than 8 elements: `x[010]` is valid and is actually `x[8]`. `1[x]` is valid and is equal to `x[1]`.)

The numerical constant must in itself be valid, and preferably not equal to `0`. (Just to prevent a parser stating `1/x[0]` is invalid!)

When replacing, insert a single space before and after your constant. This is to prevent a change of `x[1]2` to `12`. Do not use parentheses! With those, `sin x[1]` is invalid but its replacement, `sin(1)`, is.

With this, an input string

```
x[0]*x[0] + x[1] + 1
```

is translated into

```
1 * 1 + 1 + 1
```

which can be validated with regular procedures; see for example [Safe expression parser in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582403/safe-expression-parser-in-python); or, since you don't need to *calculate* but only *validate*, write your own.