# Excel like scripting language in Python for end users

Tags: python, scripting-language

I'm looking for a way to let end users process some data from the user interface. A scripting-engine with a syntax similar to Excel would do.

**Example:**

The input would be a `dict` which contains the data (which is basically variable name for the script) and a `string` with the rule.

`input = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':'add'}`

`rule_example_1 = "if(c == 'add',a+b,if(c=='sub',a-b,raise ERROR))"'`

`rule_example_2 = "if c == 'add' return a+b else if c == 'sub' return a-b else raise error()"`

The script must be extendable with own functions. Also maybe some definition of types which can be used by users.

**Use case:**

Basically the users have some 2 dimensional data in their account (product details). And using some scripting rules I would like to let them change product data.

For example if a user wants to exclude all products starting with letter `X`, they would create a rule:

`set('product_status', if(starts_with(product_title,'X'), 'skip', ''))`

or if the user wants to raise the price by 20% if the product price is lower then 10:

`set('product_price', if(product_price < 10, product_price*1.20, product_price)`

Comment: Maybe... Python?

Comment: @ddofborg: Can you provide some constraints? Basically: why *not* just let your end users write Python code?

Comment: Perhaps some additional details on what the application is about, what the scripts are supposed to do and what kind of users will be using it should give us a better idea on how to better help you.

Comment: I added two more examples. Basically 'one liner' syntax like Google Sheets or Excel would be perfect. Maybe minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want something more user-friendly, perhaps you could try Blockly:
https://developers.google.com/blockly/

You can easily integrate it with your application and customize it, creating your own blocks to serve your user's needs.

You may also want to take a look at Mesh:
https://github.com/chrispsn/mesh

Or perhaps something simpler:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simpleeval

Or, even simpler (but less safe), you can use `ast.literal_eval()`; this one is part of Python's standard library:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Also this other question may help you:
[Safe expression parser in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582403/safe-expression-parser-in-python)

Comment: I think SimpleEval (https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval) will do the work!