# How to get a Computational string like ((2*3)+(3-1))+(4/2)) and return the answer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, operators

How to get a Computational string like `((2*3)+(3-1))+(4/2))` and return the answer in python?

I can't use eval func.
the inputed pharase should include parantheses.
The program must take into account priorities when calculating.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Safe expression parser in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582403/safe-expression-parser-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Use `eval`. like this: `ans = eval('((2*3)+(3-1))+(4/2))')`

Comment: you should've mention that in the question.

Comment: you can 'cheat' by using `exec` like `exec('x =((2*3)+(3-1))+(4/2)) ')` and then accessing the variable `x`. if this is also not good, you need to create your own function for that.

Answer (score 0):

for that you gotta use the `eval()` function. It makes a string into a python code. One way to apply it would be

```
def convert_to_code(some_string):
   
   return eval(some_string)


user_input = input()

result = convert_to_code(user_input)

print(result)
```

I find it easier to have a dedicated funtion to return eval() in cases with mathematical equations that you'll have to change the value of a variable `x` multiple times. For example, if you know numerical methods, when trying to create a programm that calculates a polynomial's root, how i did it would be very usefull. But you could just use `eval()` it self.

Answer (score 0):

Get the string with `e = input("Your question :")`.
You can calcul the string with `e = eval(e)` and you can show it with `print(e)`.
The complete code :

```
e = input("Your question :")
e = eval(e)
print(e)
```

Comment: @shaqayegh78 I'm sorry but I can't help you. You can see the reply of @user14654909 on `exec` function. An example : `e = input("Your question:");f = exec("e="+e);print(e)`