# How do I make the numbers do their operation? Is there any module that can do that?

Tags: python, tkinter, math

```
def equalizer(entryblock):
    x = entryblock.get()
    entryblock.delete(0, tk.END)
    entryblock.insert('end', int(x))
```

so here is a function for my tkinter calculator. I am trying to make a function where it takes the entry box and does the operations and gives the result. For example, if I punch in '1+2+3', I want this function to turn it into 6. Whenever I try this, it gives this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1+2+3'
```

Could I use the math module to fix this problem?

Comment: A quick way to fix it would be to replace `int(x)` with `eval(x)`. I would advise against executing code that that user may have control over.

Comment: There are 2 ways to solve this problem as far as I see it. One is to use `eval` but then you cannot have the user input the values into the entry. Next is to use a AST parser, that way it will be safe from the exploits of `eval`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/MwBBA8ME) is a code for that from [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin).

Comment: Similar question: [Safe expression parser in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582403/safe-expression-parser-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to solve this problem as far as I can think:

- One is to use `eval` but then you cannot have the user input the values into the entry, as its not safe.
- Next is to implement an AST parser suitably, that way you can use user input via `Entry` and still be safe from the exploits of `eval`.
- The third way would be change your logic and make the app work like how the calculator in windows works, this way you do not need `eval` or anything. You will have to keep reference to the last item given and then add(or any operation) with the next entered item. Video reference: [Build A Simple Calculator App - Python Tkinter GUI Tutorial #6](https://youtu.be/XhCfsuMyhXo), there is a previous part but only follow the logical part of the code, the other part is quite naïve.

**For the first approach**, this should give you a bare example:

```
from tkinter import * # Note: Better to use import tkinter as tk and make changes needingly

root = Tk()

def write(num):
    lbl['text'] += num # Add the user inputted number to the end of current text from label

def calc():
    out = eval(lbl['text']) # Get the text and do the operations
    lbl['text'] = str(out) # Change the text with the output

texts = '123456789' # Digits to loop through

lbl = Label(root,font=(0,15),justify='left')
lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3)

# To create a 3x3 grid of widgets, starting from 1 because 0th row/column is already taken by the label
for i in range(1,4):
    for j in range(1,4):
        text = texts[3*(i-1)+(j-1)] # Indexing to get the respective texts
        Button(root,text=text,command=lambda num=text: write(num),width=15).grid(row=i,column=j-1)

# Some buttons outside the normal gridding behavior and with different function
Button(root,text='+',command=lambda: write('+'),width=15).grid(row=i+1,column=0)
Button(root,text='0',command=lambda: write('0'),width=15).grid(row=i+1,column=1)
Button(root,text='=',command=calc,width=15).grid(row=i+1,column=2)
Button(root,text='C',command=lambda: lbl.config(text=''),width=15).grid(row=i+2,columnspan=3,sticky='news')

root.mainloop()
```

You can design/place the widgets the way you want, notice how the function handles the input and user cant input any number as they wish either.

**For the second approach**, you can refer [here](https://pastebin.com/MwBBA8ME) for a code from [Kevin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/953482/kevin) that implements `ast` and does calculation and you can take user input as well and integrate tkinter with that function by making a few tweaks.

---

So to answer your question:

> Could I use the math module to fix this problem?

Nothing I can think of from `math` does what you are looking for.