# How to evaluate an expression in SageMath over Zmod?

Tags: python, modulo, sage

I need to compute some automatically generated expressions, which may contain square roots, with the class `Zmod`.

For example, I want to evaluate the following expression modulo 9 (thus, using the class `Zmod(9`)):

```
expr = "-1 / sqrt(7) + 5"
```

In the above case, I want to get the results 7 (for `sqrt(7) = 4`) and 3 (for `sqrt(7) = 5`).
Is this possible with Sage? How can I get these results? If I need to use another library, which one should I use and how?

I thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements of `Zmod` have an `.sqrt()` method, but you can also pass them to the `sqrt` function. Example:

```
sage: R = Zmod(9)
sage: a = R(7)
sage: sqrt(a)
4
```

If you want to automatically parse a string expression like `"-1 / sqrt(7) + 5"` and convert all numeric constants to elements of `Zmod(9)`, I'd suggest to use Sage's symbolic ring `SR` as a parser, and then traverse the expression tree using the `.operator()` and `.operands()` methods in a recursive function. Like so:

```
sage: def zmod_eval(exp):
....:     if exp.is_numeric():
....:         return Zmod(9)(exp)
....:     return exp.operator()(*(zmod_eval(op) for op in exp.operands()))
....: 
sage: exp = SR("-1 / sqrt(7) + 5")
sage: zmod_eval(exp)
7
```

This would probably handle most expressions you may have. If you want both results depending on the sign choice for the square root, then modify `zmod_eval` to return a list, and handle the sqrt operation specially. Unfortunately, Sage's symbolic ring handles sqrt as a generic power:

```
sage: exp = SR("-1 / sqrt(7) + 5")
sage: exp.op[0,0]
sqrt(7)
sage: exp.op[0,0].operator()
<built-in function pow>
```

so if your expression also contains integer powers you will have a difficult time distinguishing between them and the square root.

Ultimately, I'd think it's simpler to modify your expression generator to output `Zmod(9)` wherever is needed, rather than trying to play around with Sage.

Comment: I know, but I have to evaluate hundreds of pseudo-random expressions. I needed an automated tool to compute them all. This way I would have to calculate them "manually" one by one

Comment: Neither the title nor the question make your needs clear. Please edit them to following Stackoverflow's guidelines (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You have the full power of Python to parse the expressions and modify them. You could use, for example PyParsing for this. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582403/safe-expression-parser-in-python#3582719. But John's answer seems to be a decent solution with less effort.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to use the Sage preparser and then convert instances of `Integer` to instances of `Zmod`:

```
sage: -1 / sqrt(7) + 5
-1/7*sqrt(7) + 5
sage: preparse('-1 / sqrt(7) + 5')
'-Integer(1) / sqrt(Integer(7)) + Integer(5)'
sage: preparse('-1 / sqrt(7) + 5').replace('Integer', 'Zmod(9)')
'-Zmod(9)(1) / sqrt(Zmod(9)(7)) + Zmod(9)(5)'
sage: eval(preparse('-1 / sqrt(7) + 5').replace('Integer', 'Zmod(9)'))
7
```

This seems to work when done interactively (from the command-line or the notebook). It should be possible to convert to something that can be done programmatically: import `preparse` from the appropriate location and call it on the expression.